# MongoClient.connect not working in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb'

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err")
    } else {
        console.log("Database Connected")
    }
})
```

.connect is striked off in VS Code

err is displayed in the VS Code terminal

Node.js node-v18.12.0-x64
Mongodb version 4.2
windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: If something is striked off in the IDE this is a strong hint, that there is something wrong. Typically, the IDE also tells you *what*  the error is.

Comment: Furthermore, if your `connect` is throwing an error (that is contained in the `err` variable), it would make sense to print out that `err` variable and not just a static string `"err"`. `console.log(err)` so that you actually see what error happened ...

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. I had the same error and now it works [(found this solution from this article on official mongoDb website)](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/express-mongodb-rest-api-tutorial).

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017',{ useNewUrlParser: true ,useUnifiedTopology:true},function(err,connect) {
  if(err){
    console.log("Error!")
  } else {
    console.log('Database connected.')
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

About  Node.js node-v18.12.0-x64 Mongodb version 4.2 windows 8.1 Pro，Code below does not support.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err")
    } else {
        console.log("Database Connected")
    }
})
```

you should use as follows:

```
MongoClient.connect(url)
  .then((db) => {
    console.log('successfully...')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Failed...', err)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens to me also. I don't use the connect function for now (macOS). Try this one:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
const db = client.db('defaultDB');
```

and use it like:
`await db.collection('movies').countDocuments();`